# rewriting url in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, web-config, dotnetnuke, global-asax

hey guys,
i am using asp.net 2.0 and dotnetnuke 5.6, and using a crossarticle module, now i want that user can create multiple alias for the article.

say like below.
article/stackoverflow
stackexchange/article
etc..

say first article is linked with article id 1, and second is linked with articleid 2 then they should jump to their respective pages..
like article/1 or article/2

i can do this from web.config file... but the problem is there could be lacs of alias'es, so maintaining it in web.config file is totally flop idea. so i want to do it with global.asax file..

i tried below code:

in string variable i saved: Request.RawUrl.ToString()
and then comparing it with the url user entered and then redirecting him to appropriate page...

but i am having below issues:
i dont want user to redirect i want to rewrite url, i.e, if user enters article/stackoverflow... he should be redirected to article/1 page but url should retain.

Please anyone suggest something for this issue..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To rewrite the URL (as opposed to redirecting) you can do something like this:

```
private static void RewriteUrl(HttpApplication application, TabInfo tabInfo, string additionalQueryString)
{
    application.Context.Items["UrlRewrite:OriginalUrl"] = application.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;

    var portalAliasInfo = PortalAliasController.GetPortalAliasInfo(application.Context.Request.Url.DnsSafeHost);        
    application.Context.Items["PortalSettings"] = new PortalSettings(tabInfo.TabID, portalAliasInfo);

    var queryString = String.Format("tabid={0}" + additionalQueryString, tabInfo.TabID);
    application.Context.RewritePath("~/default.aspx", string.Empty, queryString, false);
}
```

I'd recommend doing it in an httpmodule though instead of modifying the core code.